# JasperServer - Download repository from repository browser

Tags: svn, repository, jasperserver

Is there anyway to use a regular repository browser to link to a JasperServer repository and download (back-up) the current repository?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean a regular repository server. JasperServer has its own database schema that replicates a file system in database but really has nothing to do with it. It just looks like it. As such there is no repo server that could otherwise do that. But you can use the import-export tool to export the whole repo into a file to back it all up..

Comment: Pardon my verbage, I meant the Web UI's capability for allowing a backup for a jasperserver repo.

Comment: Not in the web ui.. but on the command line you can use the import/export tool.